# How to add two subsequent list items on condition in python

Tags: python, for-loop

so I've got this list:

```
list=["00:01:15", "Some text", "00:01:40", "Another text", "00:01:55", "Yet another text", "00:02:05"]
```

I'd like to concentrate two subsequent time cues so it looks as this:

```
00:01:15 00:01:40
Some text
00:01:40 00:01:55
Another text
00:01:55 00:02:05
Yet another text
```

I'm either getting 'list index out of range' error in marked line, or the exact same two time_cues being concentrated:

```
import re
time_regex = re.compile('[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}')
list=["00:01:15", "Some text", "00:01:40", "Another text", "00:01:55", "Yet another text", "00:02:05"]
subtitle_number=0
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    if re.search(time_regex, item):
        list[index] = item
        list[index] = item + " " + list[index + 2] # <-- HERE

with open('test-1.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as ready_file:
    output = "\n".join(list)
    ready_file.write(output)
```

Can you help me refer to the next time cue with each iteraion of the loop?

Comment: Modifying the list while iterating over it is doomed. Make a new list and copy entries to it while iterating over your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using list indexing that feels a bit more Pythonic to me:

```py
>>> lst=["00:01:15", "Some text", "00:01:40", "Another text", "00:01:55", "Yet another text", "00:02:05"]
>>> for start, txt, stop in zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2], lst[2::2]):
        print(f'{start} {stop}\n{txt}')

00:01:15 00:01:40
Some text
00:01:40 00:01:55
Another text
00:01:55 00:02:05
Yet another text
```

Answer (score 1):

with `for` loop you can do this.

As you can see there is a pattern in your final output, as you are concating two times in one line and text between them in another line.

so using `for` loop,  for these 3 elements ( index 0, index 1, index 2) and concating them (index 0 and index 2) in one line and index 1 element in second line, will produce first half of the result.

Now as you need to iterate over next elemnts, see how in output index 2 elment become 1st part of the output and index 4 become second part, so a jump of 2.

so pattern will be

```
index element 0 index element 2
index element 1
index element 2 index element 4
index element 3
:
:
:
:
index element n-2 index element n
index element n-1
```

here n is the length of the list. Index element  represent the  elment value at the index in the list

since in last row, element is at `n-2` index, so we will end the indexing at `n-2` in the for loop, and add a increment of 2.

Below is the code for this

```
list_=["00:01:15", "Some text", "00:01:40", "Another text", "00:01:55", "Yet another text", "00:02:05"]
for i in range(0, len(list_)-2, 2):
     print(f"{list_[i]} {list_[i+2]}\n{list_[i+1]}")
```

output

```
00:01:15 00:01:40
Some text
00:01:40 00:01:55
Another text
00:01:55 00:02:05
Yet another text
```

And finally, it's not a advisable/good practice to name the code variables after the inbuilt python functions (eg list).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to just check if you are 2 indexes from the end.

```
import re
time_regex = re.compile('[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}')
list=["00:01:15", "Some text", "00:01:40", "Another text", "00:01:55", "Yet another text", "00:02:05"]
subtitle_number=0
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    if re.search(time_regex, item) and index < len(list)-1:
        list[index] = item
        list[index] = item + " " + list[index + 2]
print(list)
```

obviously, this may cause an issue, but it's a simple fix for this specific case.